# Google Scripts How to use the "showHeader" feature in the "applyRowBanding" function? I want to hide the header

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

Just what my title says. I have a simple function

```
sheet.getRange("A4:K"+(getMiddleRow-1)).applyRowBanding(SpreadsheetApp.BandingTheme.BLUE, false);
```

getMiddleRow just calls a certain row in my script.

I read all the documentation, which his horribly vague and it says a Boolean can be called and if it is "true" then it will show the header. So I figured if I called a "false" it would hide it, because it is showing by default. How can I get this to simple work?

Here is the documentation for it: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#applyRowBanding()

FYI, this is wrapped in a much larger function and everything else works.

When I tried to run the function without the "false" statement, everything works as expected, but with the header color.

When I add a "false" as seen above, it throws an exception.

> Exception: The parameters (SpreadsheetApp.BandingTheme,(class)) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.applyRowBanding.

Answer (score 0):

Banding Theme is supposed to be one of the following:

```
Property    Type    Description
LIGHT_GREY  Enum    A light grey banding theme.
CYAN    Enum    A cyan banding theme.
GREEN   Enum    A green banding theme.
YELLOW  Enum    A yellow banding theme.
ORANGE  Enum    An orange banding theme.
BLUE    Enum    A blue banding theme.
TEAL    Enum    A teal banding theme.
GREY    Enum    A grey banding theme.
BROWN   Enum    A brown banding theme.
LIGHT_GREEN Enum    A light green banding theme.
INDIGO  Enum    An indigo banding theme.
PINK    Enum    A pink banding theme.
```

[goto your link and click on banding theme](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/banding-theme)

If this is your code:

`sheet.getRange("A4:K"+(getMiddleRow-1)).applyRowBanding(SpreadsheetApp.BandingTheme.BLUE, false);`

then perhaps it should look like this:

`sheet.getRange("A4:K"+(getMiddleRow()-1)).applyRowBanding(SpreadsheetApp.BandingTheme.BLUE, false);`

getMiddleRow() looks like a user function to me

Comment: This is not what I was asking about. I am already familiar with the color schemes and the getMiddleRow is not a function. it is just a variable with a number attached to it.

You never addressed my question: how do I use the showHeader boolean in google script to hide the header inside a google sheet?

Comment: It seems pretty well explained here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#applyColumnBanding(BandingTheme,Boolean,Boolean)